# FindNextValidTechnique fails

Tags: c++, shaders, directx9

My effect file compiles successfully, but `FindNextValidTechnique` fails.

Technique part of the shader:

```
technique Diffuse
{
    pass Pass0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderMain();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderMain();
    }
}
```

I try to get the first valid technique after compilation:

```
pEffect->FindNextValidTechnique(NULL, pValidTechnique);
```

This returns some minus value which doesn't go along with `D3D_OK`.

I've used other flags than `D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING` to test, but no result with them either.

**UPDATE**

I've read in documentation that, "Applying Compiler Flags or Assembler Flags to the incorrect API will fail shader validation.", but I'm not sure this applies to the compile time validation or afterwards. I have no problem in compile.

I compile with these flags:

```
D3DXSHADER_DEBUG |
D3DXSHADER_NO_PRESHADER |
D3DXSHADER_FORCE_VS_SOFTWARE_NOOPT | 
D3DXSHADER_FORCE_PS_SOFTWARE_NOOPT
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debug runtime? It may have more information for you.

Comment: @P.Avery I'm in debug, but nothing. And this function doesn't return anything special really according to the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the effect without those flags?

Comment: @P.Avery I usually try all the possible ways to fix the bug. Changing flags from nothing to everything was one of it. I read in documentation that two of my flags `D3DXSHADER_FORCE_VS...` and the other one need REF or software vertex processing to work. I cut them off.

Comment: can you post the code you use to create the effect?

Comment: the call to findnextvalidtechnique should be: pEffect->FindNextValidTechnique(NULL, &pValidTechnique); be sure to reference the effect handle

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get `FindNextValidTechnique` to work and I resorted to `ValidateTechnique` instead. I used the base method `ID3DXEffect::GetDesc` to get effect description and then counted techniques through a for loop and checked each technique:

```
D3DXHANDLE* pValidTechnique = NULL;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < effectDesc.Techniques; i++)
{
    D3DXHANDLE technique = pEffect->GetTechnique(i);

    if (pValidTechnique == NULL)
    {
        if (pEffect->ValidateTechnique(technique) == S_OK)
        {
            pValidTechnique = &technique;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`ValidateTechnique` works while `FindNextValidTechnique` doesn't. Weird!

Comment: should you be using an D3DXHANDLE pointer? try D3DXHANDLE pValidTechnique; and reference the handle in the call to findnextvalidtechnique

Comment: @P.Avery This answer is my workaround and I'm OK with it. What you're saying is basically a compile time matter. I don't have such problem. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You should be using the SUCCEEDED or FAILED macros instead of checking for S_OK; also please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205835(v=vs.85).aspx where the return values for failure are given; these may assist in troubleshooting what you're doing wrong.